# Retrofit JavaRx2 thread interrupted

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm creating nested requests as following (some error handling omitted):

```
return Single.create((SingleOnSubscribe<String>) emitter -> getPages()
    .subscribe(pages -> getPageData(emitter, pages), emitter::onError))
    .compose(applySchedulers());

    // ...

private void getPageData(SingleEmitter<String> emitter, List<Page> pages) {
    service.getPage(pages.get(0).id)
            .subscribe(emitter::onSuccess, e -> {
                pages.remove(0);
                getPageData(emitter, pages);
            });
}
```

I used to have an iterative solution previously, which produced the same result. The list of pages is sorted in order and should be processed as such. This part of code works if the connection is good, however if I happen to be on a bad connection I'm getting `java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted`. What would be a good way to resolve this?

EDIT:

the stacktrace:

```
W/System.err: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
W/System.err:     at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:136)
W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:46)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1Codec.java:429)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:46)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:56)
W/System.err:     at okio.InflaterSource.refill(InflaterSource.java:101)
W/System.err:     at okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.java:62)
W/System.err:     at okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:80)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:46)
W/System.err:     at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.java:35)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingRequestBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:291)
W/System.err:     at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:1005)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readString(RealBufferedSource.java:190)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:175)
```

EDIT 2:

The getPages function:

```
private Single<List<Page>> getPage() {
        return Observable.merge(service.getPage("mn").toObservable(),
                service.getPage("fc",).toObservable(),
                service.getPage("sh").toObservable())
                .map(PageParser::parseActive)
                .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .sorted((f1, f2) -> f2.wage - f1.wage)
                .toList();
}
```

Comment: Same here. Did you try to use rxFragment ?  compile 'com.trello.rxlifecycle2:rxlifecycle-navi:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.trello.rxlifecycle2:rxlifecycle:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.trello.rxlifecycle2:rxlifecycle-components:2.0.1'

Comment: I'm already using the architecture components, this is not due to the activity being paused

Comment: please add stack trace. what is exactly `getPages()`? why are you nesting `Observables` like that, there are better cleaner ways, what do you expect that will happen with poor connections?

Comment: getPages is a retrofit request that subscribes to get `List<Page>`. How would you recommend nesting requests instead?

Comment: is this the full stack trace? getPages isn't looking like a regular retrofit request, as you're wrapping it with Single.create, please post the full code, and again what is the issue? seems like your app crashes?

Comment: Yes, the app crashes, I've added the source for getPages.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've found a solution for this :

```
private void getPageData(SingleEmitter<String> emitter, List<Page> pages) {
  try {
    service.getPage(pages.get(0).id)
            .subscribe(emitter::onSuccess, e -> {
                pages.remove(0);
                getPageData(emitter, pages);
            });
   } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
         Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
   }
}
```

You should use `rxFragment` component to interrupt rxJava2 thread when ths fragment or activity is stopped by user:

```
observable.compose(RxLifecycle.<NetworkResult, FragmentEvent>bindUntilEvent(lifecycle(), FragmentEvent.STOP));
```

But the exception ThreadInterrupted will occur because you should handle yourself the Exception for Retrofit2 and just ignore it. Doing this way works very well for me !